# OutOfMemoryException while parsing a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am retrieving an System.OutOfMemoryException while parsing an image file. Please see the code below.

Additional information:

- The image size is about 10 mb.
- 64 bit architecture with 8GB RAM
- DataTable contains more then 8000 records

```
if(dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     for ( int i=0; i< dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
     {
          string photoId = @"\\192.168.123.123\MwPict\" + dt.Rows[i]["DmCtg"] + "\\DM 3D " + dt.Rows[i]["dmcd"] + ".jpg";
          string base64 = "";
          string images = "";
          byte[] byteArray = null;
          try
          {
               // byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(photoId);
               base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(photoId));
               images = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
          }
          catch (FileNotFoundException ee)
          {
               images = "#";
          }

          byteArray = null;
          base64 = null;
          photoId = null;

          data += "<tr>";
          data += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["SR"] + "</td>";
          data += "<td><img src = '" + images + "' height = '60px' width = '60px' alt = 'photo' /></ td>";
          data += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["dmcd"] + "</td>";
          data += "<td>"+dt.Rows[i]["DmCtg"] +"</td>";
          data += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["DmPrdCtg"] + "</td>";
          data += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["DmSalCtg"] + "</td>";
          data += "<td>" + dt.Rows[i]["DsgDate"] + "</td>";
          data += "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: what is "large"? What architecture are you compiling for? 32bit? 64bit? AMD? Basically there´s not much you can do, when the task you´re executing simply does not fit into you memory.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is caused by *that* code? How big is the file? I doubt you have a 2GB image you want to embed.

Comment: I would use a loop to see if there is any limit, and then read within the loop

Comment: @Iria what for? If the error is thrown by the OP's code, a single execution is enough. On the other hand, perhaps there *is* an inefficient loop that allocates a ton of temporary objects, leading to such memory fragmentation than creating a new string is no longer possible

Comment: Every string operation creates a *new* string. This means that the code posted here creates two big strings, one for `base64` and one for `images`. The `byte[]` buffer returned by `ReadAllBytes` is another temporary object. This code ends up allocating 3 times the image's size. The way to fix this (and improve performance) is to use stream operations and write directly to the output, whatever that is. How is the `images` string used?

Comment: what can I do Now?

Comment: Don't write loops like that. Use a `StringBuilder` to construct the final string at least, with a `capacity` roughly equal to the expected size. It doesn't matter if `capacity` is too large or too small, as long as it isn't the default. Use `AppendFormat` or even `String.Format`, not string concatenations

Comment: Better yet, write directly to the output, or to a temporary file. How is `data` used? Is this written to a file? You could use a `StreamWriter` to write to a file, or `StringWriter` to write to memory through a `StringBuilder` instead of constructing the strings in memory.

Comment: On the other hand, if you write 8K records with 10MB images to a single file, you'll end up with an 80GB file. Is that what you really want? If you do, you'll have to write to an output file directly, not keep anything in memory.

Comment: yes I want is it possible if i use stream writer then It will work??

Comment: why in the world would you want an 80gig file or anything larger than each image... its not usually done like this due to running into all sorts of "performance" considerations.

Comment: instead store the files locally... fetch if it densest exist... if it does.. then put relative path instead of fetching and embedding, or use the path as source if it has access..

Comment: the web page will most likely also take forever to load (crash)... this is bad idea on many fronts

Comment: Is there any reason why you try to build some sort of html string within your code? Just saw that your question is tagged with asp.net. And I am sure there are way better solutions to your needs.

Comment: I doubt you want to load all the 8000images at once. Instead you may show only a few - e.g. 10 per page - and let the user switch between those pages.